# Expanded ListView only works with one nested Column, but no more than that? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart

So I have had this bug for the past two days. I have tried a lot of things from the internet based on the errors I am getting from flutter,but one issue/solution leads to another problem. Or it is simply not what I want done. Essentially what I want is this:

[Header1][Header2][Header3]

[LiveFeed1][LiveFeed2][LiveFeed3]

So my layout is like this.

Column1->Row1, Row2

Row1->Expanded1(), Expanded2(), Expanded3()

Row2->Expanded(ListView1), Expanded(ListView2), Expanded(ListView3)

Currently I am just trying to get at least one of the listviews to work that way I have something I can depend on. However, the only way I can get it to work is: Column(Expanded(ListView)) which is not what I want. The other way is (which I cannot really remember because I tried so many permutations) is through the use of shrinkwrap:true. However two issues arise, 1 my app bleeds, 2 I cannot scroll.

This is my code:

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    leading: Icon(Icons.dashboard),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.close),
          onPressed: () {
            _auth.signOut();
            Navigator.pop(context);
            //TODO: Implement logout functionality
          }),
    ],
    title: Text('Title'),
    backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        //JobsOnBoardList(),
        rowWithHeader(),
        rowWithDetails(),
      ],
    ),
  ),
  floatingActionButton: getButton(),
);
  }

  Row rowWithHeader() {
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Expanded(
      child: Card(
        child: Text("Header1"),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: Card(
          child: Text("Header2"),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: Card(
        child: Text("Header3"),
      ),
    ),
  ],
  );
  }

  Row rowWithDetails() {
return Row(
  children: <Widget>[
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        OnBoardList(),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        OnBoardList(),
      ],
    ),
    Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        OnBoardList(),
      ],
    ),
  ],
   );
 }
 }


class _OnBoardList extends State<OnBoardList> {
final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

@override
void initState() {
// TODO: implement initState
getCurrentUser();
super.initState();
}

void getCurrentUser() async {
try {
  final user = await _auth.currentUser();
  if (user != null) {
    loggedInUser = user;
    print(loggedInUser.email);
  }
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
 }

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return MessageStream();
 }
}

 class MessageStream extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   // TODO: implement build
   return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  //stream: _firestore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
  stream: _firestore.collection(all_jobs_created_collection).orderBy('TimeCreated').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {

    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(
          backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
        ),
      );
    }

    final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
    List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
    for (var message in messages) {
      final messageText = message.data['Field1'];
      final messageTimeStamp = message.data['Field2'];
      //print("=====Messages======");
      //print(messageText);
      //print(messageTimeStamp);
      final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
        timeStamp: messageTimeStamp,
        text: messageText,
      );
      messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
    }
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        reverse: true,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
        children: messageBubbles,
      ),
    );
  },
);
 }
}
```

Comment: when you return the row of `OnBoardList()`, why do you wrap each one with a `Column`?

Comment: I would have put the `rowWithDetails()` inside an `Expanded` widget to explicitly make sure there is a size allocated to it.

Comment: To be honest I am new to flutter, and i was just following the pattern from the video I was watching. I am new to app development as whole and I am still getting the hang of it. So to answer your question Zvi Karp, I don't know why I did that.

Answer (score 0):

So removing Column to every ListView did not work alone.
Wrapping rowWithDetails() with an Expanded did not work alone.

However, doing both at the same time did. Therefore, I removed the columns to ListViews (OnBoardList()) and I wrapped (rowWithDetails) with an expanded widget. I am not sure with the formalities of StackOverflow, but Tom and Zvi Karp answered my question. Thank you.

Old Code:

```
   Row rowWithDetails() {
   return Row(
     children: <Widget>[
       Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           OnBoardList(),
         ],
       ),
       Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           OnBoardList(),
         ],
       ),
       Column(
         children: <Widget>[
           OnBoardList(),
         ],
       ),
     ],
      );
    }
    }
```

New Code:

```
       Expanded rowWithDetails() {
       return Expanded(
         child: Row(
           children: <Widget>[
             OnBoardList(),
             OnBoardList(),
             OnBoardList(),
           ],
         ),
       );
     }
   }
```